# Why {${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^*}$} is regular but {${ww|w∈(a+b)^*}$} is not $? $

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I read [this site example 12](https://gatecse.in/identify-the-class-of-a-given-language/)  that  {${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^*}$} the set of strings generated by language $L$ is {${ϵ,a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,aaa,…}$} by taking always $w$ as $\epsilon$ and $x$∈$(a+b)^∗$. But  my question is why they taking always $w$ as $\epsilon$ to prove it is regular. In that same logic why $ww$ isn't regular by taking $w$ as $\epsilon$?

Comment: Because if you take $w$ as $\epsilon$ you can produce *any string*. Nothing is added to the set with other values of $w$, because they are already present. Please remember that a string is just a string. It does not magically retain the mechanism by which it was produced.

Comment: @rici If I take $x =a$ and $w=a^nb^n$, then how can you say it is regular for first language?

Comment: That subset is not regular but that doesn't matter. The question is whether the language as a whole is regular. And it is, because any string composed of $a$ and $b$  is in the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take $w=\varepsilon$ in the second language, you can only create the word $ww = \varepsilon \varepsilon = \varepsilon$. This is not the case in the first language because of the $x$ factor that gives you all the freedom of choice you need.

Comment: If I take $x$ $= a$ and $w= a^nb^n$, then how can you say it is regular for first language?

Comment: @Saslok The word you describe is $aa^nb^n$ which is clearly in the language for $x = aa^nb^n$ and $w = \epsilon$. A language is a set. $\{xww|x,w∈(a+b)^*\}$ is only one possible description of that set, but that description is not the language itself. You cannot impose arbitrary additional requirements (which is what you are doing), you can only check whether a word is in the set or not. And all words over $\{a,b\}$ are in this set.

Comment: @idmean please elaborate with example "A language is a set. ${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^∗}$ is only one possible description of that set, but that description is not the language itself".

Comment: @Saslok Well, you can just change variable names for a start $\{yuu|y,u∈(a+b)^*\}$. Or, since we have already established that the language is equivalent to $\{a,b\}*$, you could just write that. Or you could come up with something more convoluted like  $\{yu|y \in (a+b)^*, u \in \{\epsilon, aab, baa\}  *\}$. The point here is that it doesn't matter which values can occur after the prefix $y$ (which can be any word over $\{a,b\}$) as long as the suffix $u$ (or $ww$ in the original description) can be empty. Then, clearly, your language is equivalent to $\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: @idmean thank you.. But I want to understand what is description and language?  $x=aa^nb^n$ is one possible description of the language {${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^∗} $} ?

Comment: @Saslok A language is a set of words. Sets can be given in many different ways. I recommend you learn more about set theory if you're not sure what something like $\{ (a, b) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a + b = 2  \}$ means. $x=aa^nb^n$ could be a language if given as $\{ x | x = aa^nb^n,  n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Otherwise it's just some term up to interpretation. Note that I only made a distinction between description and language because that's where your confusion stems from. The distinction is not very relevant normally.

Comment: @idmean you mean {${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^∗}$} is possible description of the language $L$ $=$ {${epsilon, a, b, aa, bb...... }$} but why you wrote  " {${xww|x,w∈(a+b)^∗}$ isn't language $L$ itself"?

Comment: @Saslok Because you seemed to assume that $x$ and $w$ can somehow be fixed. This is only one of many ways to describe the same language. $x$ and $w$ are not relevant for the words in the language. This is only a description of how to generate these words. In this sense, this is not the language itself but a recipe for generating all words in the language.

Comment: @idmean when we write $L$= {${xww| x, w ∈(a+b)^∗}$} means {${xww| x, w ∈(a+b)^∗}$} is one possible description of $L$ where $L$ is $\sum^*$.But  {${xww| x, w ∈(a+b)^∗}$} isn't $\sum^*$. Am I right?

Comment: @Saslok No, you're wrong, $\{xww\mid x,w\in (a+b)^*\} = \Sigma^*$. The inclusion $\subseteq$ is trivial. The inclusion $\supseteq$ is due to the fact that any word $u \in \Sigma^*$ can be written $xww$, with $x = u$ and $w = \varepsilon$.

Comment: @Nathaniel I want to understand what is description and language?

Comment: A language is a set of words. I don't think there is a formal definition for "description". You can see it as a way to "describe" the language (thanks Captain Obvious), like "$1+1$" is a different way to describe "$2$", same as "$3-1$". There may be several descriptions of the same mathematical object.

Comment: @Nathaniel  {${xww∣x,w∈(a+b)^∗}$} $=$ $Σ^∗$ is same as $L$ where language $L$ $=$ {${epsilon,a,b,aa,bb......}$}?

Comment: @Nathaniel inclusion $⊇$  please explain little bit...

Comment: @Saslok I can't say anything more than what I have already explained. Just take the time to re-read what I have said.

Answer (score 1):

We know that , any language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$. Hence union $\Sigma^*$ with any other languages is
$\Sigma^*$. Note that $x$ is  $\Sigma^*$, and one of the strings that can be obtained from $ww$ is $\epsilon$, so concatenation $x$ with $ww$ can be as bellow:

$$\Sigma^*\cup \dots=\Sigma^*.$$

So actually  $L$ is $\Sigma^*$ that already  we know it's regular, because there is DFA for it.